Problem in React using DataTable with Bootstrap5
I am using this DataTable, which works correctly, the problem is that when I run it I get this error: “DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see https://datatables.net/tn/3“, the solution was to use the following: ‘if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(’#example”)) {
$(“#example”).DataTable().destroy();
}”. But now I have a new problem and I get a very wide and empty column at the end of the table, do you know how to solve it?
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import "datatables.net-bs5";

function MyDataTable() {
  const [users] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Axel",
      primerApellido: "Rojero",
      segundoApellido: "Flores",
      curp: "HFKJALSITOSPR9AISK",
      rfc: "DJU8ALS9F0SLD",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "Kira",
      primerApellido: "Garfias",
      segundoApellido: "Gonzalez",
      curp: "HFKJALSITOSPR9AISK",
      rfc: "DJU8ALS9F0SLD",
    },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#example")) {
      $("#example").DataTable().destroy();
    }

    $("#example").DataTable({
      autoWidth: true,
      paging: false,
      searching: true,
      colReorder: true,
      fixedHeader: true,
      responsive: true,
      stateSave: true,
      columns: [
        { title: "Numero de empleado" },
        { title: "Nombre" },
        { title: "Primer apellido" },
        { title: "Segundo apellido" },
        { title: "CURP" },
        { title: "RFC" },
        { title: "Editar" },
        { title: "Borrar" },
      ],
    });
  }, [users]);

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <h2>Docentes</h2>
      <div className="col mb-3">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
          Agregar Usuario
        </button>
      </div>
      <table
        id="example"
        className="table table-striped table-bordered"
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Numero de empleado</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Primer apellido</th>
            <th>Segundo apellido</th>
            <th>CURP</th>
            <th>RFC</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
            <th>Borrar</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <tr key={user.id}>
              <td>{user.id}</td>
              <td>{user.nombre}</td>
              <td>{user.primerApellido}</td>
              <td>{user.segundoApellido}</td>
              <td>{user.curp}</td>
              <td>{user.rfc}</td>
              <td>
                <button className="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button className="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyDataTable;


Error
DataTable pre-destruction: Used $(“#example”).DataTable().destroy() before each initialization to avoid duplication when re-rendering the table.
Use of useEffect: Table initialization is performed inside useEffect, ensuring that the table is properly destroyed before being re-created.
Disabling of certain settings: Properties such as autoWidth and responsive were disabled to eliminate possible conflicts that could be causing the duplications.
